# Using Euler's method, solve system of differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Using Euler's method, solve system of differential equations $Y'=AY$ if $$A= \begin{bmatrix}
    8 & -1 & 5 \\
    -2 & 3 & 1 \\
    4 & -1 & -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

$$-$$ I've been reading about this method, and I saw that all examples with this metho have some time step $h$ or initial value $y(t_0)=y_0$, but here I don't have anything. Can I solve this like Nonhomogeneous constant-coefficient linear differential equations or to solve this with eigenvalues(I heard about this way, but I don't know how to do that)..

Comment: As you observed, the task description is incomplete without an initial value. One could take as canonical place-holder the identity matrix  $Y_0=I$. This then would approximate the fundamental (matrix-valued) solution.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot solve it without an initial value, at least you can write down the recurrence.

Let $SJS^{-1}$ be a diagonalization of $A$.
Given an initial condition $y_{0}=Y(t_{0})$ and a step size $h$, Euler's method defines the sequence of iterates $y_{1},y_{2},\ldots$ by
$$
y_{n+1}=\left(I+hA\right)y_{n}\qquad\text{for }n\geq0.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
y_{n}=\left(I+hA\right)^{n}y_{0}\qquad\text{for }n\geq0.
$$
Using the fact that
$$
I+hA=SS^{-1}+hSJS^{-1}=S\left(I+hJ\right)S^{-1}
$$
we get
$$
y_{n}=S\left(I+hJ\right)^{n}S^{-1}y_{0}\qquad\text{for }n\geq0.
$$
As for the actual values of $S$ and $J$, [according to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize%20%7B%7B8,-1,5%7D,%7B-2,3,1%7D,%7B4,-1,-1%7D%7D)
they are
$$
S\approx\begin{pmatrix}-0.502512 & -5.7963 & 2.63214\\
-0.354525 & -26.7138 & -0.598336\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$I+hJ\approx\begin{pmatrix}1-2.65552h\\
 & 1+2.52861h\\
 &  & 1+10.1269h
\end{pmatrix}.
$$